# Logstash-5.X Kafka Input plugin : no message read from kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, logstash-configuration

Planned to upgrade my ELK setup to 5.x along with that I tried to add kafka message queue between forwarder and logstash server on the new environment.

There is no issues on forwarders sent message to kafka. I verified it through kafka consumer script.

But when I pull message from kafka using logstash-kafka-input plugin, its not writing any messages . Should I need to add/enable any specific settings in my configuration ?.

my logstash simple config :

```
input {
kafka{
    topics => ["weblogs"]
    bootstrap_servers => "10.11.12.202:9092"
}
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
 file {
                 path => "/tmp/stdout.log"
           }
}
```

Kafka Consumer script output on the topic :

```
[root@logstash kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0]# bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic weblogs
10.11.12.169 - - [27/Apr/2017:13:50:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 287 "-" "check_http/v2.0.3 (nagios-plugins 2.0.3)"
192.168.10.11 - - [27/Apr/2017:13:50:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 281 "-" "check_http/v2.0.3 (nagios-plugins 2.0.3)"
10.11.12.169 - - [27/Apr/2017:13:50:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 291 "-" "check_http/v2.0.3 (nagios-plugins 2.0.3)"
10.11.12.169 - - [27/Apr/2017:13:50:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 289 "-" "check_http/v2.0.3 (nagios-plugins 2.0.3)"
```

Comment: What do you see in the logs of logstash?

Comment: there is no log message other than logstash started event message. any idea please

Comment: Please launch logstash in debug (/usr/share/logstash# bin/logstash -f path/to/logstash.conf --log.level debug) mode and share the logs.

Comment: @berrytchaks pls find the debug message https://paste.ubuntu.com/24630775/

Comment: any chance to check it.  pls help to resolve this problem. thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really feeling fine these days. Please can you share your version of kafka and logstash. See this for compactibility purposes https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html

Comment: Version : logstash-5.3.1-1.noarch , kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0. Only input plugin option not working. whereas I can write into kafka without no issues means logstash-kafka-output have no issue. Only issues with logstash-kafka-input plugin

Comment: I'm using `logstash 5.2.2` and `kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0` and it is working perfectly. Please can you used `logstash 5.2.2` instead.

Comment: sure, I will. if you don't mind, could you please share your example configuration for my reference.

Comment: Any update @KMG.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145273/discussion-between-kmg-and-berrytchaks).

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic configuration with which I get it working.

```
input {
  kafka { 
        bootstrap_servers =>["kafkaIp:9092"]
        topics => ["topic1"]
        codec => "json"
        group_id => "logstashgroup"
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["http://elasticsearchIp:9200"]
      manage_template => true
      index => "indexname"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic logstash configuration to take input from kafka and forward it to elasticsearch.

```
input {
 kafka {
    bootstrap_servers =>["kafka1:9092"]
    topics => ["kafka-topic"]
    codec => json {}
}
}

output {
elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    manage_template => false
    index => "kafka-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
}
}
```